# Does calling APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN.REMOVE_WORKSPACE with P_DROP_USERS => 'Y' drop the user objects?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I noticed that in the [Oracle documentation for APEX_INSTANCE_ADMIN](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_instance.htm#AEAPI252), you can drop the user by setting the `P_DROP_USERS => 'Y'` flag.

Is the drop operation in this procedure equivalent to `DROP USER CASCADE CONSTRAINTS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  I checked the source code.  It does DROP USER  CASCADE.

Comment: Any chance you can link the source?

Comment: Are you asking for the source code for this specific action?  The entire PL/SQL package?  If you could narrow your specific question, that may help.

Comment: Either - I just wanted a link to the source so that I could have a look at it myself and anyone else that had this question can do so as well.